# writing xml into mysql in for each loop

Tags: mysql, insert, for-loop

I have pulled values from an xml file which i need to store. I now need to get this data into my mysql database. I have done a complex for each loop with multiple levels so I am wondering how I would go about putting this in to a MYSQL insert statement. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Example

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$game = $xml->xpath("//market");
foreach ($game as $event)
{
    if (strpos($event['name'], 'Match Betting') !== false)
    {

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (feedid, homeid, homeodd, drawid, drawodd, awayid, awayodd)
        VALUES ("echo $event['id'] .", ";
            {
                foreach ($event->children() as $prices)
                    {
                        echo $prices['id'] . ", ";
                        echo $prices['odds'];
                    }
            }
        ")");
    }
}
?>
```

The above really doesnt work and is a little stupid but I really cant think how to do this.

Help please :D

Answer (score 0):

dont use foreach loop inside the mysql statement. instead use the sql in the foreach loop. try it and inform if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this but no joy, I am probably doing something stupid :(

<?php

$source = file_get_contents("text.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$game = $xml->xpath("//market");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (feedid, homeid, homeodd, drawid, drawodd, awayid, awayodd)
  VALUES (

foreach ($game as $event)
{
 if (strpos($event['name'], 'Match Betting') !== false)
 {
  
  echo "'" .$event['id']."', ";
   {
    foreach ($event->children() as $prices)
     {
      echo "'" .$prices['id']."', ";
      echo "'" .$prices['odds']."'";
     }
   }
  
 }
}
)");
?> 

Any ideas?

Comment: you are inserting into only 3 columns. why not all ?

Comment: Im inserting into 7, the foreach loop goes through the XML file and generates 7 elements

Comment: even if it is, you have written the values for only 3 attributes. i suggest you put up a piece of xml also for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

XML: http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&typeId=295&marketSort=MR&filterBIR=N

Result of my foreach statement is:

http://www.footballadvisor.net/hills.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6123/discussion-between-raghav-bhushan-and-user989952)